# Migration is reapplied while trying remove it

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

We use `context.Database.Migrate();` at runtime (application `Main` method) to apply migrations. This does not seem to work in conjunction with

```
Update-Database <RevertToMigration>
Remove-Migration
```

when trying to revert and remove a migration. The `Remove-Migration` command ends up calling the same code which re-applies the migration that was just reverted. Am I calling the correct commands? Is there a way to determine in the code whether or not the `Remove-Migration` command is being called (and therefore skip calling `Migrate()`)? The `DbContext` is configured using the `OnConfiguring` method.

Comment: "at runtime" is too broad. Where exactly are you calling `context.Database.Migrate()`? And what method for [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) are you using?

Comment: "at runtime" meaning "from the application `Main` method". The `DbContext` is configured using the `OnConfiguring` method.

Comment: In other words, [from application services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services) - somewhere (probably wrong place). Try implementing [From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory), it's the most reliable way to separate "design time" from "run time".